# How to call an Array between classes?

Tags: java, arrays

Hello I am new to java so please be gentle,

```
class Result{
   public float Mean(){
       //find the mean of the array
   }
   public float lowest(){
       // find the lowest
   }

}
```

---

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         float arr[] = {1.1,2.2,3.3};
    }  
}
```

What I want to do is to take the array `arr` from `Main`, and bring it to class `Result` so that I can use it
in `Mean()` and `Lowest()`.

Thank you.

Comment: You pass the array as a parameter. How to do so is covered in most Java tutorials (that it's an array isn't terribly relevant; it's still just a parameter).

Comment: Java programming conventions have methods and variables start with lower case letters (ex. mean).

Answer (score 2):

Try add the array  as part of constructor of Result/Solve, then you could work with numbers inside the instance you create.

```java
class Solve {
   final float[] numbers;
   public Result(final float[] numbers){
     this.numbers = numbers;
   }
   public float mean(){
       //find the mean using the this.numbers

   }
   public float lowest(){
       // find the lowest using this.numbers
   }

}
public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float numbers[] = new float[]{1.1,2.2,3.3};
    Solve solve = new Solve(numbers);
    float mean = solve.mean();
    float lowest = solve.lowest();
    
    System.out.println("Mean: " + mean);
    System.out.println("Lowest: " + lowest);
  }
}
```

Another option is to make your methods static and pass the numbers as part of the methods, similar to `Math` class.

```java
class Solve {
 
  public static float mean(float[] numbers){
  
  }
  
  public static float lowest(float[] numbers) {
 
  } 
} 

public class Main{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float numbers[] = new float[]{1.1,2.2,3.3};
    float mean = Solve.mean(numbers);
    float lowest = Solve.lowest(numbers);

    System.out.println("Mean: " + mean);
    System.out.println("Lowest: " + lowest);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your array as an argument to the other object’s method.

```
float[] arr = { 1.1F, 2.2F, 3.3F } ;

Result r = new Result() ;
float output = r.lowest( arr ) ;
```

Define that argument on the method.

```java
class Result{

   public float mean( float[] input ){
       // … find the mean of the array
   }

   public float lowest( float[] input ){
       // … find the lowest
   }

}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/wG4uvA).

Passing an argument/parameter to a method is a basic minimal skill in Java. You should study the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) by Oracle, and consult a textbook to get the basics down.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Comment: @matt Re: #2, to find the lowest value?

Comment: @matt The question does not ask about static, nor does it ask about how to architect a Java app. The question asks how to pass a primitive.

Comment: @matt Regarding #1, Yes, it compiles. See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/wG4uvA).

Comment: @matt Regarding #2, the point of having `r.lowest(arr)` is because the Question asked for it. Let’s answer the Question *as it was asked*, not invent a new Question.

Comment: @matt It follows the OP's original code structure. As for static/non-static, that's a different discussion, but that said: moving functionality to instantiable objects is generally easier to modify and test without resorting to test-time bytecode manipulation via Mockito/PowerMockito/etc.

Comment: @matt You're right, it would not imply a static method taking an array. This post follows the OP's original structure, and correctly. Re: compilable--hogwash: code fragments are 100% acceptable.

Comment: @matt YMMV. I don't think it's a poor answer at all: it doesn't hand the solution to the OP, which is good. It provides enough information to get started, which is good. It provides a general structure based on the OP's original code, which is good. I don't see the issue(s), but we can agree to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would handle this:

Result class:

```
class Result {
    public static float mean(float... arr) { //make the method static, and have it take the array as a parameter
        float sum = 0f;

        for (float f : arr) { //add each number in the array to the sum variable
            sum += f;
        }

        return sum / arr.length; //return sum / length, which is average
    }

    public static float lowest(float... arr) { //same as the above method
        float lowest = arr[0];

        for (float f : arr) { //loop through the array
            if (f < lowest) { //if this number is lower than the current "lowest" number, set lowest to be this number
                lowest = f;
            }
        }

        return lowest; //return the lowest number
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float[] arr = new float[] { 1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f }; //here's the array
        System.out.println(Result.mean(arr)); //I pass it to the method as a parameter
        System.out.println(Result.lowest(arr)); //same here
    }
}
```

An alternative solution would be to use Java streams instead of for loops.  Java streams can get more complicated than for loops, but they can be much cleaner and easier to read.  Here's how I would rewrite the Result class using streams:

```
class Result {
    public static float mean(float... arr) {
        return (float) IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                .mapToDouble((i) -> arr[i])
                .average()
                .getAsDouble(); //returns the average of the array
    }

    public static float lowest(float... arr) {
        return (float) IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
                .mapToDouble((i) -> arr[i])
                .min()
                .getAsDouble(); //returns the minimum value in the array
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced this is the best answer for a Java beginner ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you very much for your feedback.  Could you please elaborate on what this answer is missing?

Comment: I think it is a bit overcomplicated for a beginner. I believe the point of the OP is to get the result using some essential knowlege.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong It's not *missing* anything. For someone new to Java, and likely doing an assignment meant to demonstrate loops, function calls, basic operations, etc. it introduces many new concepts.

Comment: Thank you again for the feedback.  I have updated the answer to use a normal for loop instead of a stream, which is probably easier for a beginner to understand.

Comment: *shrug* I might have left the original answer as an "alternative" solution since it's about as clean as Java can ever be, or specifically called out that it may be more advanced usage. In your defense, the OP did not state any solution requirements, so it was a perfectly *valid* answer.

Comment: Using `Arrays.stream(arr)` instead of `IntStream` would simplify it.

Comment: You can't stream a float array.  `Arrays.stream()` is only meant for the largest of each type of primitive, so in this case a double array, which we don't have.  The whole IntStream thing is just a way to convert a float array to a double stream, since there is no such thing as a primitive float stream.